# Clase mysqli, procedimiento insert y sentencias preparadas con campos null, sysdate(), now(), fallan

Tags: php, mysqli, poo, clase, class

Estoy usando una clase en php para las tareas mas frecuentes en mi base datos, conexión, inserción, actualización, borrado y sentencias preparadas...

Estoy teniendo verdaderos problemas cuando quiero insertar un null en un campo, o 'campos calculados' como now(), sysdate()... no solo en las sentencias preparadas, sino en un simple insert. Al pasar estos tipos de datos los interpreta como cadenas por lo que les añade comillas, quedando así, 'now()' o 'null'... por lo que las sentencias cascan.

Este es un ejemplo para que puedan ver a lo que me refiero:

*INSERT INTO cur_access_codes (id_curso, codigo, fecha_ini, fecha_publicacion) VALUES ('1761', 'TEST', **'null'**, **'now()'**)*

He partido de esta librería **https://github.com/bennettstone/simple-mysqli/blob/master/class.db.php**, la he intentado modificar para solventar este problema, pero no doy con la solución.

Estoy totalmente perdido

¿Alguien tiene una librería que solucione estos problemas?¿Como lo hacen ustedes?

Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: now() y null pertenecen al motor del base de datos por lo que no se envian entre comillas, adicional si un campo es null solo no lo envias asi `INSERT INTO cur_access_codes (id_curso, fecha_publicacion) `  por otra parte si el campo fecha_publicacion siempre es la hora del insert puedes darle un default now() a ese campo y tambien lo eliminas solo enviarias id de curso

Answer (score 0):

por favor deberías mostrarnos la parte del código en donde se pasan las variables a la librería para ver como lo estas haciendo.

Según lo que he visto la librería recibe un array como parámetro.

Posiblemente el problema sea cuando creas el Array para pasar a la librería,
de esta forma.

```
    $campos = [ 
       'id_curso'  => $id,
       'codigo'    => $codigo,
       'fecha_ini' => 'fecha_ini',
       'fecha_publicacion' => now()',
    ];
```

Esto es una suposición, porque no sabemos todavía como tu lo haces.

Si este es el caso, o es algo parecido , podrías mejorar la forma en que preparas el array para evitar eso.

Ejemplo

```
    $now = date("Y-m-d");

    $campos = [ 
       'id_curso'  => $id,
       'codigo'    => $codigo,
       'fecha_ini' => $fecha_ini ? "$fecha_ini" : "",
       'fecha_publicacion' => "$now",
    ];
```

el código

```
       'fecha_ini' => $fecha_ini ? "$fecha_ini" : "",
```

Verifica que $fecha_ini no sea null o vacio y devuelve $fecha_ini ,en caso
contrario devuelve una cadena vacia .

La Variable $now como tu querías, tiene la fecha actual.

Espero te ayude
Saludos